# Get 3 results from searching a List of xy Points that satisfies a condition c#

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have a `List of Structs` that holds an **Id**, and values for **x**  and **y** coordinates:

```
public struct XYStruct
        {
            public int vertexId;
            public double x;
            public double y;
        }


List<XYStruct> myList = new List<XYStruct>();
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 0, x = 0, y = 0});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 1, x = 20, y = 0});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 2, x = 40, y = 0});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 3, x = 60, y = 0});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 4, x = 80, y = 0});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 5, x = 100, y = 0});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 6, x = 0, y = 10});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 7, x = 20, y = 10});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 8, x = 40, y = 10});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 9, x = 80, y = 10});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 10, x = 100, y = 10});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 6, x = 0, y = 20});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 7, x = 20, y = 20});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 8, x = 40, y = 20});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 9, x = 80, y = 20});
myList.Add(new XYStruct{ vertexId = 10, x = 100, y = 20});
```

For each item in list there is a increment in `dx = 20` and an increment `dy = 10`

I want to get the `vertexId` of item that is at right,down, and rightdown of the current vertex

for instance if vertexId is `0` I want to return

```
Down vertex = 6
Right vertex = 1
Right Down Vertex = 7
```

I am trying

```
var right= myList.SingleOrDefault( v => v.x  == myList[0].x + 20 && v.y  == myList[0].y);
int resRight = right.vertexId;

var down= myList.SingleOrDefault( v => v.y  == myList[0].y + 10 && v.x  == myList[0].x );
int resDown = down.vertexId;


var downRight = myList.SingleOrDefault( v=> v.x == myList[0].x + 20 && v.y == myList[0].y + 10);
int resDownRight = downRight.vertexId;
```

Is it possible to make more efficient this queries?

Comment: Seems duplicate vertexes are allowed, correct ? How many vertexes are you estimating in average ?

Comment: the max vertices I am estimating are 4000, but I would like to avoid duplicates, is it possible? maybe using a Hash Map or something would improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a dictionary it would look like this:

```
Dictionary<Int32, XYStruct> x_index = new Dictionary<int, XYStruct>();
Dictionary<Int32, XYStruct> y_index = new Dictionary<int, XYStruct>();
XYXYStruct s = new XYStruct { vertexId = 0, x = 0, y = 0 };
x_index.Add(s.x, s);
y_index.Add(s.y, s);

XYStruct item_by_x_index = x_index[0];
XYStruct item_by_y_index = y_index[0];
```

first you create the object and later your store the pointer to it in both dictionarys.

If you want to have an index on 2 values, you would need to "nest" Dictionarys into each other like

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, XYStruct>>
```

but structs like that do tkae some time for implementation. For 4k objects, that would probably by an overkill.

if the assignment x-coordinate => XYStruct would not be unique, you would need to work with something like

```
Dictionary<int, List<int, XYStruct>>
```

with is then pretty close to your "hashmap", except it doesn't hash. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could build something similar to a database index. 
For Example, you could use an additional Dictionary. Then you could access your object very easy by using the distionarys []-Operator.

This would cost the efford for keeping your dictionarys synced, but it will save a lot of time if the Lists are getting really big.

Are you absolutly sure, your criterium for getting the object is "unique"? SingleOrDefault will throw an exception, if multiple entries in your list match your filter.

Comment: yes `SingleOrDefault ` that is where I am getting trouble, could you please post an example of how to search in a dictionary as you commented?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems reasonable to me(for a given constraints), however, few things you could improve to gain performance and/or readability.

1. Have a `Dictionary` instead of `List` to read elements based on vertex (directly) with `O(1)` access, or use [`indexer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) implementation.
2. Are you sure you'll have single element for given search criteria? if not I would suggest using `FirstOrDefault`

-.

```
Dictionary<int, XYStruct> points = ...;
int vertex =0; // specify position

var right= points.FirstOrDefault( v => v.x  == points[vertex].x + 20 && v.y  == points[vertex].y);
if(right != null)
{
    int resRight = right.Value.vertexId;
}
```